# Error in rendering all element of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

Hi I have an array called wincolor generated by a loop that contains 243 elements in it. and I have another array called uniqueparty that applies filter to all the elements in wincolor. the problem i am facing is that when uniqueparty is rendered it renders only 9 of the 243 elements from wincolor. it needs to render all 243 element. Can some one help me sort this error out?

```
var resultData = [];
      var uniqueparty= [];
      var wincolor = [];
     $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1IoNqeReOPKNFrYMlK2rnJVuMaLeAgnZneLbKYSQ7bs4/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {
        var len = data.feed.entry.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
             //first row "title" column
             var current = data.feed.entry[i];
             resultData[i]= [
              current.gsx$constituency.$t, //0
              current.gsx$winner2010.$t, //1
              current.gsx$winningparty.$t, //2
              current.gsx$candidatename1.$t, //3
              current.gsx$party1.$t,//4
              current.gsx$candidatename2.$t,//5
              current.gsx$party2.$t,//6
              current.gsx$candidatename3.$t,//7
              current.gsx$party3.$t//8
              ]; 
              wincolor[i]=[current.gsx$winningparty.$t];
            }
            uniqueparty = wincolor.filter(
              function(a){
                if (!this[a]) {
                  this[a] = 1; return a;
                }
              },{}
            );
            document.write("Unique Party: "+uniqueparty.length+"<br>");
            document.write("Wincolor: "+wincolor.length);
          });
```

Comment: I would remove the API key and show us an example of data. Also you can change  `wincolor[i]=[current.gsx$winningparty.$t];` to add  `if (wincolor.indexOf(current.gsx$winningparty.$t) ==-1) uniqueparty[uniqueparty .length]=current.gsx$winningparty.$t; wincolor[i]=[current.gsx$winningparty.$t];` and drop the filter

Comment: You need to return true from your filter function to keep the element, looks like you aren't doing that?

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/6L8b9eLr/

Comment: @Lee thanks for the quick reply do you mind guiding me on how to do it I am still learning to do the coding so will appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lee is correct - your filter function needs to return true or false, to indicate whether you want to keep or discard the element. Here's a quick example of a filter which only accepts animals with the letter "i" in their name:

```
<script>
  var animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'fish', 'gorilla', 'elephant', 'chicken', 'rhino'];
  var filtered = animals.filter(
    function(element, index, array) {
      if (element.indexOf('i') !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  );
  console.log(animals);
  console.log(filtered);
</script>
```

You can find documentation on the Array.filter method here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter